# How can I automatically "click" a button when a timer counts down to "0"? (How do I call click on a button from code?)

Tags: javascript, timer, buttonclick

I am preparing an exam page. I have a time counter and it counts back from 60 seconds down to 0. There is a button `NEXT`, I want to skip to the next question when the time ends for the question. When you select your answer through the radio buttons and click `NEXT`, the page redirects to the next question, but when the time is up, I want the `BUTTON` be clicked automatically in order to skip to the next question.

Here is my code for counter :

```
function startResetTimer() {

    time = 60;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        time--;
        document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = "" + time + " seconds"
    }, 1000)
}
```

The remaining time is shown on the label `label1` and the name of my button is `SubmitButton`.

Comment: Call `click()` on the button element.

Comment: function startResetTimer() {

    time = 60;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        time--;
        document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = "" + time + " seconds"
    }, 1000);
    if (time==0) {
          click("SubmitButton"
    }

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469795/trigger-an-aspbutton-click-event-using-javascript (use the `click()` form shown)

Comment: You get the idea but invocation more like `document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click()`

Comment: Edit of the post is not correct for `SubmitButton`, it's not the `name` of the button...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Automatically clicking a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144459/javascript-automatically-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Gillesc, thank you, works perfectly, here is the final code, next question comes when the timer reaches "0"..:

Comment: function startResetTimer2() {

    time = 60;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        time--;
        document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = "" + time + " seconds";
if (time==0) {
document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click()
    }
    }, 1000);
    
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
interval = setInterval(function() {
    time--;
    document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = "" + time + " seconds"
    if (time == 0) {
        // stop timer
        clearInterval(interval);
        // click
        document.getElementById('thebutton').click();            
    }
}, 1000)
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/cmtqzwa7/

Comment: @BahadirAlkes Does this answer your question? Any update?

Comment: Sorry DDan, my fault, thank you very very much. I had used this code and still am.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.